# Export image of the plot by code - Netlogo

Tags: image, plot, get, export, netlogo

how can I export an image of the area of the plot by code?
I'm using Netlogo 5.0.5. 
I'm tring to reproduce the comand "copy image" of menu right-button of the mouse in the area-plot in tag "Interface".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no primitive to export a plot as an image in NetLogo, which is admittedly a hole in the language. It would be fairly simple to write an [extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions) to do that, but as far as I know, none exists.

That leaves you with two alternatives:

- Use [`export-plot`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#export-plot), which will give you a CSV file, and recreate your plot using some other tool (e.g., [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/)). This is more work, but it has the advantage of giving you better quality output in the end, NetLogo plots being kind of bitmappy anyway...
- Use [`export-interface`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#export-interface) to export the whole NetLogo interface tab as an image, and then crop the resulting picture to keep only your plot. If you use a command-line tool like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/), this can be fully automated.

In both cases, you could try calling the external program that you choose directly from NetLogo by using the [Shell extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/Shell-Extension/).

Comment: Thanks. I hope at something better and more easy.